# Connect() threads wxWidgets

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I am building an app that uses threads with wxWidgets.
I have use the documentation and http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication#Sending_events_to_the_main_thread to understand how it is done, but I have a slight problem.

Althrough I my src code is almost idential to the one abovementioned, I can't get my main process to react to the event that the thread placed in his eventqueue.

I suspect that there is something wrong with the Connect() function, but I can not figure it out. Could someone please have a look at the code below - thank you for your time.

thread.cpp

```
void* entry(){
// retriving text from the clipboard
wxCommandEvent event( wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED,UPDATE_CLIPBOARD );
event.SetString(temp.GetText());  
parent->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent( event );
}
```

main.cpp

in the constructor:
    Connect(UPDATE_CLIPBOARD,wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED,wxCommandEventHandler(ENTRIES::UpdateFromClipboard));

and then later one:

```
void ENTRIES::UpdateFromClipboard(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("Test"); // is never called
}
```

can anyone spot the error in this code ?

Comment: I figured it out... I called the wrong eventhandler! parent->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent( event );  should have been parent->mywindowOBJ->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent( event );  I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Create an answer and mark it accepted. Useful for others in the future.